# Plot Time values with matplotlib

Tags: python, time, matplotlib

I have a sample text file as follows:(test.txt)

```
06:00:41 2
06:10:41 4
06:20:41 6
06:25:41 8
```

I want to plot this taking time value for X-Axis and the 2nd column to the y axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import time
import numpy as np


f2 = open('test.txt', 'r')
lines = f2.readlines()
f2.close()


x1 = []
y1 = []


for line in lines:
    p = line.split()
    a = time.strptime((p[0]),"%H:%M:%S")
    x1.append((a))
    y1.append(float(p[1]))

xv = np.array(x1)
yv = np.array(y1)


plt.plot(xv, yv)

plt.show()
```

This is how I plot it. But the X-Axis shows 500,1000,1500 etc. Instead I want to show the time values as 06:00:41,06:10:41,06:20:41 etc. Please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`plot_date`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=plot_date#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot_date)?

It may help if you put your time series data as [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) values

```
from datetime import datetime

for line in lines:
    p = line.split()
    xv.append(datetime.strptime(p[0], '%H:%M:%S'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(xv, yv)
```

If you want a line plot, try changing the `linestyle` ([docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle))

```
ax.plot_date(xv, yv, linestyle='-')
```

Comment: Additional help : Why this is shown as a scatter plot?I want to have it as a line?